# Método de seleccion en c++? (Ordenamiento con listas doblemente enlazadas)

Tags: c++, ordenamiento, método

hicé un código para ordenar por método de selección una lista doblemente enlanzada, segun yo funcionaba y todo bien, pero cuando lo revisé con mas de 10 elementos ya no funciona, solo con pocos. Si por favor alguien nota que hago mal, agradecería mucho que me lo dijera, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
class Node{
    public:
        int element;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        Node(int element){this->element=element; next=NULL; prev=NULL;}
};

void doubleList::orderSelection(){
    int min, aux;
    if (first->next==NULL)
        return;
    else{
        Node *p = first;
        while(p != NULL){
            min = p->element;
            Node *j = p ->next;
            while(j != NULL){
                if(j->element < min){
                    aux = min;
                    min = j->element;
                    j->element = aux;
                    p->element = min;
                    j= p->next;
                    break;
                }
                j=j->next;
            }
            aux = p->element;
            min = aux;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿No tienes algún ejemplo de datos con los que funciona y datos con los que no funciona? ¿Puedes incluir la definición de `Node`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si, con mas de 6 datos no funciona por lo que revisé. Te puedo mandar una captura si gustas.

Comment: Nada de capturas, [las imágenes no se pueden copiar-pegar o compilar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers). Pon datos de ejemplo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ah sí perdon, tengo una función rand para añadir los datos por cantidades, le pusé para añadir 7 datos que fueron: 478,224,169,0,334,467,41. Luego los "ordené" y quedaron así: 224,169,0,334,467,41,478.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ahora un ejemplo que si funciona, hicé lo mismo pero ahora con 5 elementos, se añadieron: 41,467,334,0,169, estos si los ordenó correctamente.

Comment: La lista de elementos **sin ordenar** ¿ la muestra correctamente ?

Comment: Si, esa la muestra como es.

Answer (score 1):

```
        while(j != NULL){
            if(j->element < min){
                // ...
                j= p->next; // 1
                break;
            }
            j=j->next; // 2
```

En (1) actualizas `j` y en (2) asumes que es un puntero válido. Si resulta que `p` es el último elemento de la lista entonces `j` valdrá 0 y el programa morirá al ejecutar (2).

Te faltan chequeos para evitar acceso a punteros no válidos

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que me dices pero no estoy segura de como resolverlo, se me ocurrio ponerle un if antes de la linea (1); if (j != last). Le pusé eso pero aun así no funciona.